# Locate regex strings with repeats or a sliding window

Tags: r, regex

Given the following:

```
# 123456789X12345678  # locator numbers for reference
 "TESTHEHEHETESTHEHE"
```

I would like to locate all positions of the string "HEHE". The desired output would be 5, 7, and 15. The trouble is the immediate "repeat" of "HEHE" after position #5. So if I use `stringr::str_locate_all`, I get:

```
stringr::str_locate_all("TESTHEHEHETESTHEHE", "HEHE")
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     5   8
[2,]    15  18
```

Which misses the match beginning at position #7.

Comment: `str_locate_all("TESTHEHEHETESTHEHE", "(?=HEHE)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, that's pretty neat and not how I currently think of positive lookahead. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: Lookahead check is tried at every location in the string, one by one, from left to right.